# Creating a responsive product grid. What's up with my widths?

Tags: html, css, width, responsive-design

I've created a container with a `width:90%` (and 10% of padding) and within it are three `display:inline` divs with a `width:30%`

This didn't have the desired effect, I wanted the three divs to stretch to 30% of the container, thus filling the whole container.

First go creating something responsive. I intend to put my images within these divs with a max-width to create a responsive grid of products.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abrdn/)

As you can see the product divs are simply stretching to the size of the text, when I want them to expand to fill the content area.

[Live example](http://www.rubytuesdaycreative.co.uk/testsite/shop.html)

**CSS:**

```
.shoppg #content{
  width:90%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
}

.product{
width:30%;
display:inline;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
      <div class="product">
        product 1
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        product 2
      </div>
      <div class="product">
        product 3
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/abrdn/6/

Basically, you need to float them to get them to meet your requirement of filling to fit the div.

But **since your ultimate goal here is a responsive design**, you need to give your product divs a fixed width, otherwise, they won't go from being on the same row to being vertically stacked when the display becomes too small.  Like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/abrdn/10/

Notice how the divs instead go to another row, instead of simply squishing together and getting smaller when you use a percentage width.

You can extend this a little furth, to do a fixed `min-width` with a percentage `width` to allow it to fill, but then go to a new row once the min-width is reached, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/abrdn/12/

Comment: This is absolutely perfect. I hadn't actually planned to make this fully responsive and stackable, but now you've helped me out with this it's inspired me! I'll have to work on the header and nav now I guess. Though seeing how easy creating a responsive grid is, it's not actually as bad as I thought!

Comment: It is important to learn a lot of this by hand/manually, but when you begin to feel comfortable with positioning, you should look into - `media queries` (which you'll need to make the same site look pretty on multiple devices) and then into a framework like `twitter bootstrap` which offers a clean/neat way to implement what you're talking about now.

Comment: Also, I realized that there is a third/better way for what you're looking for.  Please see the third example in my answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused at one point... why does the product have a width of 100%? It should be 30% no?

Comment: Are you talking about the 3rd example? It is `100px` not `100%`

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to float `.product`

```
.product{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    display:inline;
}
```

If you float an element, the `display` property is useless, but `display:inline` [fixes an IE7 issue](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer/floatIndent.html).

Some resources:

- http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: true, but the display: inline ruins everything

Comment: Why @Ibu ? Don't see any...ruin

Comment: Can you let me know where the display:inline is ruining things so I can browser test? What system are you running?

Answer (score 1):

`display:inline-block;` + `float:left;` because inline-block adds weird `margin`/`padding` to the box model. But shouldn't `.product`'s width be `33.33333%` because you are dividing #content's width by 3?
Then use `width:100%; height:auto; display:block;` for the images and they will fill and stretch all day.